# Java searching float number in String

Tags: java, regex, floating-point

let's say i have string like that:

> eXamPLestring>1.67>>ReSTOfString

my task is to extract only 1.67 from string above.

I assume regex will be usefull, but i can't figure out how to write propper expression.

Comment: SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807433/java-string-manipulation-extracting-integer-and-float-from-string-based-on-patt

Comment: float f=Float.parseFloat(yourstring);

Answer (score 11):

If you want to extract all **`Int`'s** and **`Float`'s** from a **`String`**, you can follow my solution:

```
private ArrayList<String> parseIntsAndFloats(String raw) {

    ArrayList<String> listBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(raw);

    while (m.find()) {
        listBuffer.add(m.group());
    }

    return listBuffer;
}
```

If you want to parse also **negative values** you can add **`[-]?`** to the pattern like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
```

And if you also want to set **`,` as a separator** you can add **`,?`** to the pattern like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]*\\.?,?[0-9]+");
```

.

To test the patterns you can use this online tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

*Note*: For this tool remember to unescape if you are trying my examples (you just need to take off one of the **`\`**)

Answer (score 3):

You could try matching the digits using a regular expression

```
\\d+\\.\\d+
```

This could look something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("eXamPLestring>1.67>>ReSTOfString");
while (m.find()) {
    Float.parseFloat(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it in one line,

```
String f = input.replaceAll(".*?(-?[\\d.]+)?.*", "$1");
```

Which returns a blank String if there is no float found.

If you actually want a `float`, you can do it in one line:

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(input.replaceAll(".*?(-?[\\d.]+).*", "$1"));
```

but since a blank cannot be parsed as a `float`, you would have to do it in two steps - testing if the string is blank before parsing - if it's possible for there to be no float.

Comment: What if there is no number in the String at all? It just returns the original String instead of an empty String.

Comment: @FabZbi I modified the regex to return a blank if there's no float - I just added a `?` after the capture group to make it optional.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String s = "eXamPLestring>1.67>>ReSTOfString>>0.99>>ahgf>>.9>>>123>>>2323.12";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(">> "+ m.group());
    }
```

Gives only floats

```
>> 1.67
>> 0.99
>> .9
>> 2323.12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `\d*\.?,?\d*` This will work for floats like 1.0 and 1,0

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this **[link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)**, they also explain a few things that you need to keep in mind when building such a regex.

`[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`

example code:

```
String[] strings = new String[3];

    strings[0] = "eXamPLestring>1.67>>ReSTOfString";
    strings[1] = "eXamPLestring>0.57>>ReSTOfString";
    strings[2] = "eXamPLestring>2547.758>>ReSTOfString";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");

    for (String string : strings)
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("# float value: " + matcher.group());
        }
    }
```

output:

```
# float value: 1.67
# float value: 0.57
# float value: 2547.758
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Extracts the first number out of a text.
 * Works for 1.000,1 and also for 1,000.1 returning 1000.1 (1000 plus 1 decimal).
 * When only a , or a . is used it is assumed as the float separator.
 *
 * @param sample The sample text.
 *
 * @return A float representation of the number.
 */
static public Float extractFloat(String sample) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d.,]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        return null;
    }

    String floatStr = matcher.group();

    if (floatStr.matches("\\d+,+\\d+")) {
        floatStr = floatStr.replaceAll(",+", ".");

    } else if (floatStr.matches("\\d+\\.+\\d+")) {
        floatStr = floatStr.replaceAll("\\.\\.+", ".");

    } else if (floatStr.matches("(\\d+\\.+)+\\d+(,+\\d+)?")) {
        floatStr = floatStr.replaceAll("\\.+", "").replaceAll(",+", ".");

    } else if (floatStr.matches("(\\d+,+)+\\d+(.+\\d+)?")) {
        floatStr = floatStr.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\\.\\.+", ".");
    }

    try {
        return new Float(floatStr);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new AssertionError("Unexpected non float text: " + floatStr);
    }
}
```