# How to Sum String double Value

Tags: java, android

I have a string like `24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km`.

I want to compute the sum of all the distances in the string but I'm not able to do it. I'm getting a `NumberFormatException`.

Here is my code

```
String stringValue = getDistanceOnRoad(lat, long, lat2, long2);
double sumValue = 0.0;

Log.d("my string is", stringValue);
try {
    sumValue = Double.parseDouble(stringValue);
    Log.d("distance there plus", String.valueOf(sumValue));
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("not a number");
}
```

I'm getting the distance from this method, everything is working fine but I'm not able to compute the sum of all distances.

[How to calculate distance between two locations using their longitude and latitude value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu)

```
private String getDistanceOnRoad(double latitude, double longitude,
        double prelatitute, double prelongitude) {
    String result_in_kms = "";
    String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="
            + latitude + "," + longitude + "&destination=" + prelatitute
            + "," + prelongitude + "&sensor=false&units=metric";
    String tag[] = { "text" };
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);
        if (doc != null) {
            NodeList nl;
            ArrayList args = new ArrayList();
            for (String s : tag) {
                nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(s);
                if (nl.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node node = nl.item(nl.getLength() - 1);
                    args.add(node.getTextContent());
                } else {
                    args.add(" - ");
                }
            }
            result_in_kms = String.format("%s", args.get(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result_in_kms;
}
```

Comment: what is `s1` ???

Comment: I have changed.

Comment: Since when is `24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km` a number? I guess the exception is deserved.

Comment: then what is `stringValue` ??

Comment: how to sum it. I want total sum of it.

Comment: "24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km"

Comment: is it possible to sum of all?

Comment: Please write your answer in formatted codes.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is. In particular, you did not even make a try to calculate the sum.

Comment: Do some research before directly postion a question here.  Regex will be easy solution, Have look into [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234963/java-searching-float-number-in-string) .

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez, if you want to answer. Please post an actual answer

Comment: @SunilKumar Code for you:
public class KmCalculator {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    String distanceToBeSummed = "24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km";
    String [] distanceArray = distanceToBeSummed.split(" km");
    double totalDistance = 0;
    for (int index=0; index < distanceArray.length; index++) {
      totalDistance = totalDistance + Double.parseDouble(distanceArray[index]);
    }
    System.out.println(totalDistance);
  }
}

Comment: Please read question agains

Answer (score 1):

If your string is like 24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km, then before converting it to double you should parse the string.

```
String stringValue = getDistanceOnRoad(lat, long, lat2, long2);
double sumValue = 0.0;

Log.d("my string is", stringValue);
try {
  String[] distances = stringValue.split(" km");
  for (String distance: distances) {
    sumValue = sumValue + Double.parseDouble(distance);
  }
  Log.d("distance there plus", String.valueOf(sumValue));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("not a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem there is that you're trying to parse `String S = "10.1 km";` to a double variable. However, the "km" part of the String isn't a number, so the java compiler isn't able to parse it. Instead define a double variable for the number of km: `double km = 10.1` and a String variable for "km". Then (when you want to get It as an String)  redefine the variable for km with the answer of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String test = "24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km";
String[] parsedString = test.split("(km)");
double sum = 0;
for(String s : parsedString) {
    sum += Double.parseDouble(s.trim());
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: Oh. I have tested on my computer and everything is ok. Can you give me the string you wanna sum? I'll check again

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String s = "24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km";

String[] items = s.split("km");
double result = 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++) {   
    result = result + Double.parseDouble(items[i]); 
}

System.out.print("result = " + result);
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: what is your exact string ? because its working fine in above string

Comment: My Log.d String => D/my string is: 24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km

Comment: @S.Ali still with me, my solution is working fine with above string.

Answer (score 0):

You should split by km, then sum the values, here is the method :

```
private static double parseAndSum(String string) {

    double sumValue = 0.0;
    String[] nums = string.split("km");

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        sumValue += Double.parseDouble(nums[i].trim());
    }
    return sumValue;
}
```

And here how you call it :

```
String string = getDistanceOnRoad(latitude, longitude, prelatitute, prelongitude);    
double result = parseAndSum(string);
System.out.println("Total is : " + result + "km");
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" –

Comment: I just ran it, check the screenshot attached.

Comment: My Log.d String => D/my string is: 24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km

Comment: hmm. I have seen your's screenshot it's working but i don't know why i'm getting Invalid double: ""  error.

Comment: so the method getDistanceOnRoad returnes the string "24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km" ?

Comment: replace latitude, longitude, prelatitute, prelongitude with your values and try

Comment: Dear sir, I'm getting correct km of my distance.. But i'm not able to sum of all km

Comment: well, assuming you are sure about the returned string, the method must work as I tested it.

Comment: yes sir, method is working fine -> I had get it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu

Comment: print the string returned from the method, is it the same as the one you mentioned in the question?

Comment: Ok, give me 1 min. i'll give u log.d

Comment: D/distance there: 24.5 km
D/distance there: 10.1 km
D/distance there: 30.9 km

Comment: these results are coming in different values, not in the same string, you see D/. While your original question's string is "24.5 km10.1 km30.9 km"

Comment: hmm, i understood. thank u so much for your answer i'll try. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: hi, I have used your method in getdistanceonroad(), I'm not getting any error but i'm not able to get sum value of it.   double sumVaue = 0.0;
                sumVaue+=parseAndSum(result_in_kms);
                //sumVaue+=sumDigits(test);
                Log.d("distance there", String.valueOf(sumVaue));

Comment: My Log D:   is D/distance there: 24.5
D/distance there: 10.1
D/distance there: 30.9  how to sum it

Comment: did you go solution?