# Regular expression for a string of a particular pattern

Tags: java

Say I have a String like below

```
String s1 = "This is a new direction. Address located. \n\n\n 0.35 miles from location";
```

now I want to extract "0.35 miles from location" only. I'm more interested in "0.35" to compare this number with something else.

The String s1 may be of following pattern as well.

```
String s1 = "This is not a new direction. Address is not located. \n\n\n 10.25 miles from location";
```

or

```
String s1 = "This is not a new direction. Address is located. \n\n\n 11.3 miles from location";
```

Pls help me to achieve the result. Thanks!

I tried this

```
String wholeText = texts.get(i).getText();
if(wholeText.length() > 1) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9].[0-9][0-9] miles from location");
    Matcher matcg = pattern.matcher(wholeText);
    if (match.find()) {
        System.out.println(match.group(1));
    }
```

But I don't know what to do when it's xx.xx miles...

Comment: No. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does you string may contain other numerical values ?

Comment: what specifically is the pattern?

Comment: You may notice that this site is called "StackOverflow", not "WriteMyCodeForMeOverflow". Try to solve your problem yourself, and then ask about any problems you might run into.

Comment: Extract floating numbers ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234963/java-searching-float-number-in-string

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807433/java-string-manipulation-extracting-integer-and-float-from-string-based-on-patt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for any number formatted as ...ab.cd...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s  = "This is a new direction. Address located. " +
            "\n\n\n 0.35 miles from location";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234963/java-searching-float-number-in-string